# Google continues to index Word documents and PDF files that were blocked by robots.txt and have been removed from the server

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, search-results

I've been having some issues removing some content from Google's search results. I have some word documents and pdf files in public directories that I have since password protected. When you try to access any of the documents you are prompted for a user name and password. The documents have also been completely removed from the server.

I did have a disallow on the directories in my robots.txt but this didn't seem to do the trick either.

I've also been adding the urls to the temporary removal tool but they just expire and appear back in the results.

Any suggestions on how to completely remove the content that used to be in these directories from Googles search results? The urls currently return a 401. Would a 410 be more effective?

Comment: Are they still blocked in robots.txt?   Googlebot will never see that they are removed if it can't crawl them.

Comment: No, I removed the block from robots.txt. Would that be the case for a 401 as well? Since Google can't access the document it will keep it in it's index?

Comment: I've removed the password protection and I'm letting everything 404 for the time being. I'm trying to add a 410 response code to those directories but it's not working.

Comment: How long have you waited?  It may take Google a month or more to re-crawl everything.  Once it crawls each document, it should remove it from the index within 24 hours after getting a 404 error.

Comment: Well, I've had the directories password protected for well over a month. I just now removed that password protection and let the urls 404.

Comment: Depends how many you have... if a few hundred it could take several months for Google to recrawl them since 404's will only be discovered when Google crawls the URL again, sometimes it can take Google one or two visits to actually remove them as well because it has to be convinced that the 404 is not temporary. You should opt to use 410 Gone as that is a better signal that it is gone forever.

Answer (score 2):

Google have two tools to remove content from search.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal

This will remove the content for temporary(90 days), and it may index the content again as you said in your question.

And this is new tool, I don't know when they launch it, but it work's really great for me.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

This tool have only two rules, if the content return 4xx error, simply remove it from search results ASAP, no matter you own the site or not.

[image]

It's damn good, I successfully remove search results from github site as well, which return 404 error.